# which dropbox app type to choose when creating app for use with livecode and mergext dropbox external

Tags: ios, external, dropbox, livecode

what app type do i have to choose when creating an app for use with Livecode and the dropbox external of mergExt suite? API or Chooser?

Comment: check out https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser and https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core  Sounds like Chooser is for web apps.  and core API for iOS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes API. Chooser is a javascript API to add a Choose From Dropbox button to your website.